# DeprecationWarning: grpc.load: Use the @grpc/proto-loader module with grpc.loadPackageDefinition instead

Tags: javascript, firebase

I keep getting this warning in the console:

```
DeprecationWarning: grpc.load: Use the @grpc/proto-loader module with grpc.loadPackageDefinition instead
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

---

package.json:

```
{
    "main": "src/index.ts",
    "scripts": {
        "start-live": "ts-node ./src/index.ts",
        "start": "nodemon"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/express": "^4.16.1",
        "@types/node": "^11.9.5",
        "express": "^4.16.4",
        "firebase": "^5.8.4",
        "nodemon": "^1.18.10",
        "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
        "ts-node": "^8.0.2",
        "typescript": "^3.3.3333"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This means that a package that you depend on is calling the deprecated function `grpc.load`. You can determine which package is doing this by adding the following to your index file:

```
process.on('warning', e => console.warn(e.stack));
```

This will output the stack trace of the warning. Once you know which package is calling it you can file an issue with them to upgrade their code.